# Solve analytically the time-independent Schrödinger equation for the Hamiltonian $\hat H$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

The Hamiltonian $\hat H$ is given by:

$$\hat H=\frac{1}{2}(\hat p^2+\hat q^2)+K(\hat p\hat q+\hat q\hat p)$$
where $K$ is a real constant, in the coordinate space:
$$\hat p=-iℏ\frac{\partial}{\partial q}$$
$$\hat q=q$$

I try to solve it by expanding those operater, and end up with:
$$\hat H=-\frac{ℏ^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2}+\frac{q^2}{2}+K[(-iℏ)\frac{\partial}{\partial q}q+(-iℏ)q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}]$$

$$\hat H=-\frac{ℏ^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2}+\frac{q^2}{2}+K(-iℏ)[(1+q\frac{\partial}{\partial q})+q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}]$$

$$ \hat H=-\frac{ℏ^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2}-i(2Kℏ)q\frac{\partial}{\partial q}+(\frac{q^2}{2}-iKℏ)$$

However I don't know how to solve the second order differiential equation:
$$\hat H\psi=E\psi$$

$$-\frac{ℏ^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial q^2}-i(2Kℏ)q\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial q}+(\frac{q^2}{2}-iKℏ)\psi=E\psi$$
$$-\frac{ℏ^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial q^2}-i(2Kℏ)q\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial q}+(\frac{q^2}{2}-iKℏ-E)\psi=0$$
$$\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial q^2}+i\frac{4K}{ℏ}q\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial q}+\biggl(\frac{2E}{ℏ^2}+i\frac{2K}{ℏ}-\frac{q^2}{ℏ^2}\biggl)\psi=0$$

Can someone give me some hints? Or correct me if I am using a wrong approach.

Comment: It is likely reducible to a hypergeometric equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation, perhaps even something simpler, like parabolic cylinder functions or confluent hypergeometric. The way to start is to try to reduce it to one of the canonical forms by writing $\psi(q) = f(q)\phi(q)$ and choosing $f(q)$ in such a way as to have a constant coefficient in the last term.

Comment: Do you have a mass term in your Hamiltonian? I think this can be converted to a standard differential equation with a solution that can be written in terms of Laguerre Polynomials.

Comment: Another option is re-writing it as a particle in a constant magnetic field and parabolic potential... then you change the gauge, reducing it to a harmonic oscillator... and then you transform back to the original gauge.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is quite useful to notice that the last term in the Hamiltonian reduces,
$$K(pq+qp)=K\left[pq+(i+pq)\right]=2Kpq+iK,$$
with help of $[q,p]=i$ with $\hbar=1$. Then, we have
$$H=\frac{1}{2}(p^2+q^2)+2Kpq+iK.$$
The first terms can be rewritten with help of ladder operators,
$$p=i\sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2}}(a^{\dagger}-a),\quad q=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega}}(a^{\dagger}+a).$$
Next, it seems that in terms of ladder operators the first terms simply gives
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)\left(a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
whereas the second term gives
$$\frac{iK}{2}(-aa^{\dagger}+a^{\dagger}a)=-\frac{iK}{2},$$
where I tacitly assume that you are interested in averages $\langle n|a^{\dagger}a|n\rangle$. Finally, we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega+\frac{1}{\omega}\right)\left(a^{\dagger}a+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{iK}{2}$$
and it looks like the QHO with constant energy shift.

However, I am not sure that everything is correct. The differential operator that you have write down is so close to the differential operator in the Landau levels problem and it seems that [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533937/landau-levels-in-rotationally-invariant-gauge) can help

Answer (score 2):

A [Bogoliubov transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogoliubov_transformation) to new operators $\hat b$ and $\hat b^\dagger$
\begin{align}
\hat b= u\hat a+v\hat a^\dagger\, ,\qquad \hat b^\dagger u^*\hat a^\dagger +v^*\hat a
\end{align}
with $\vert u\vert^2-\vert v\vert^2=1$ and suitably chosen $u$ and $v$ will bring $H$ to a diagonal form.

Alternatively, this Hamiltonian is expressible in terms of generators of the $\mathfrak{su}(1,1)$:
\begin{align}
 \hat K_+&=\frac{1}{2}\hat a^\dagger\hat a^\dagger \qquad 
        \hat K_-=\frac{1}{2}\hat a\hat a\qquad 
        \hat K_0=\frac{1}{4}(\hat a\hat a^\dagger+\hat a^\dagger\hat a)
\end{align}
and can be diagonalized $UHU^\dagger=H_d\sim K_0$ by a transformation of the form $U=\exp(-i\Lambda K_x)$ for suitable $\Lambda$.  If you need to find the eigenkets, it is then a matter of finding the action of $U$ on the kets $\vert n\rangle$: this can be found in

> Ui, H., 1970. Clebsch-Gordan formulas of the SU (1, 1) group. Progress of Theoretical Physics, 44(3), pp.689-702,

or in

> Perelomov, A., 2012. Generalized coherent states and their applications. Springer Science & Business Media.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but multiple suggestions for attacking the problem:

**Brutal force**
The equation is likely reducible to a [hypergeometric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation), perhaps even something simpler, like parabolic cylinder functions or confluent hypergeometric. The way to start is to try to reduce it to one of the canonical forms by writing ψ(q)=f(q)ϕ(q) and choosing f(q) in such a way as to have a constant coefficient in the last term.

**Analogy with magnetic field**
Another option is re-writing it as a particle in a constant magnetic field and parabolic potential... then you change the gauge, reducing it to a harmonic oscillator... and then you transform back to the original gauge.

**Actually, it is an oscillator...**
One could even try diagonalize the quadratic form in the Hamiltonian, introducing new position and momentum operators.

Comment: I am curious to what would be your choice of gauge transformation.

Comment: By *gauge* I mean that $B_z = \partial_xA_y -\partial_yA_x$, and we have multiple choices of $A_x, A_y$. Textbooks usually solve Landau levels for $A_x = By$, but one can do it for any choice of gauge, which are related by a canonical transformation. Nice homework problem, btw ;)

Comment: i think you cannot write it as a particle in a constant magnetic field. If you rearrange this equation from OP's post you find that $\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2}(\hat{p}+2K\hat{q})^2 + \frac{1}{2}(1-4K^2)\hat{q}^2 $. If you see $\vec{A}(\hat{q}) = 2K/e \hat{q}$, therefore $\vec{B}= 0$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Still, it reduces to an oscillator,  as the other answer demonstrates in details.